# Yarn workspaces problem: Yarn decide "put" some dependencies in the workspace, not in the "root" node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I have a project made of two workspaces:

- **client** (Angular 8) in `packages/client`
- **server** (NestJS) in `packages/server`

This is the root `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "workspace-demo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "packages/*"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is **the problem**: for some reason, after adding some dependecies to the client and/or server (dependencies from Angular and NestJS), Yarn decided to move `@nestjs` dependecies into `packages/server/node_modules` instead of putting it in the **root `node_modules` folder**. That is that dependecy was moved from `node_modules/@nestjs` to `packages/server/node_modules/@nestjs`.

Contents of `packages/client/package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.7",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Contents of `packages/server/package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^6.7.2",
    "@nestjs/core": "^6.7.2",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^6.7.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.7.7"
  }
}
```